# Number of test cases needed

Tags: testing

Question:
You are making a web site for children. When a child creates their account, s/he enters a birthdate. Depending on the age of the child, there are limitations on what data can be collected and what the child can do. Children younger than 8 and adults 18 or older are not allowed to use the site. Children aged from 8 up to 13 have one set of permissions, while children aged from 13 up to 18 have another. How many test cases are needed to cover all the equivalence partitions?

My professor says the answer can be 8 or 11. 
We have 4 partitions of people and 2 sets of permissions. So we test each group with each set. So we get 8, is this the right way to get the answer 8?

How about the 11? What other factors are being taken into account to get this answer?

Thanks

Comment: My guess would be: 42

Comment: Serious. What is a test case?

Comment: Take into consideration what happens to an active registered user, who has a birthday occur during website usage period.

Comment: @TopherEllis What do you mean by "a birthday occur during website usage period"? Could you please explain it further?

Comment: "My professor"...is this homework?

Comment: @BruceJinruSu: If a user is registered and using the site at a given age of 13, and the next day when the user logs in, the system sees the user is now 14.  How are permissions handled?  Will the user be notified when content has changed?

Comment: Can't see anywhere in the question, that justifies all these assumptions. It's almost as if you are meant to say given there are 11 test cases, what design would make that the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a combinatorial kind of question but greatly depends on your concrete implementation.  In my eyes, there are only four test cases:

- Children younger than 8 are principally refused
- adults 18 or older are principally refused
- children from 8 to 13 must have permission set A
- children from 14 must have permission set B

Edit:
There's more test cases:

- What happens if the user becomes eighteen while using the site.
- The user becomes 14 while being logged in.

Comment: Don't forget - children who're 13 can become 14 and thus have to get a new set of permissions and one who's 18 can turn 19 and not be allowed in, so there needs to be a permission change function to be tested as well

Comment: Thx for the hint. Didn't see that. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen, that's about when you test to see if they have a permission. If that's every time, transition is not an issue, if it's on log on, then they have to log off an on again...

Comment: @TonyHopkinson But the ability to change permissions is functionality which needs to exists , and therefore - if talking test cases - one that needs to be considered.

Comment: Depends on the implementation, and what's meant by test case doesn't it. If you have to log off an on again, there is no change of permission within the software, therefore no need to test anything, or write anything, or deal with what the concept of permissions changing on the fly. In my opinion, I'd be checking to make sure permissions could not change. Course we are both making assumptions...